# Jquery Slide - touch slider

Tags: jquery, slide

Estou usando o JS cycle para fazer um slide de PARCEIROS no meu site.
Estou desenvolvendo o responsivo dele e queria que também desse para passar com o dedo para o lado(somente no MOBILE).

Tem algum jeito de no celular ele puxar outro jquery ou um plugim que faça no desktop ficar FADE e no mobile ficar TURN?

SIte: somospixel.com

Site do plugim: http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/

```
Javascript:
       $("#slide").cycle({
                       fx: 'fade',
           speed: 1200,
           timeout: 5000,
            pause: 1,
         pager:'#botao'   
        });
```

Comment: parece que tem duas perguntas aqui, você quer saber como realizar swipe no mobile ou que no desktop fique FADE e mobile fique TURN?

Comment: No normal que seria desktop ja está FADE, agora quero que apenas no mobile eu consiga passar pro lado com o DEDO essa div #slide